# What do I call the presentation of the final result of my research?

Tags: phrase-request, terminology

My situation: I have done the research and before I defend my dissertation I have to make a presentation of the final result. I am having difficulty finding the right term for this seminar. In my native language, we normally call it "the seminar of the final result" but that sounds too long in English. My research is considered to be done when I have passed this seminar/presentation, then it can be published. When I fail, I have to change the topic and start it from the beginning. The audience is the commissioner of supervisors.

Can I say "seminar result" for the presentation that is conducted before a dissertation is published? Or can  I only use "final seminar"?

Comment: I don't understand the concept you're trying to convey so I'm not sure what words to use for it. "Seminar result" is definitely wrong, though: it seems you want to be talking about the seminar but "seminar result" is using "seminar" as a modifier to the noun "result".

Comment: I am translating it from my native language, but I doubt if I can find a suitable term for it in English @DavidRicherby I have done the research and before I defense my dissertation I have to make a presentation of the final result.

Comment: There will certainly be a way of saying what you want to say in English. If you can describe the situation you're asking about in more detail, I'm sure somebody will be able to help. Just a guess: if you mean the examination or presentation that a student gives before e.g., a PhD thesis is accepted, this is called a "defence" or, in British English, a "viva voce examination" (often abbreviated to "viva").

Comment: I'd hang on and wait for someone with more PhD experience :)

Comment: @Araucaria The essential context is the term, not the degree.

Comment: I'm not sure that seminar is the right word for a presentation of your research before you defend your dissertation. Who is the audience for your presentation? A seminar is typically used to mean something like a class or course but without credit toward a degree for those that attend.

Comment: Side note: "defense" is a noun, but you're using it as a verb. You should say "defend my dissertation".

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to say. What do you mean by "result"? "Result" means the outcome or effect of something. We don't normally talk about a dissertation having a "result". Do you mean the final version or revision of your dissertation?

Comment: *thesis presentation*?

Comment: Your research is considered to be done when you pass this seminar/presentation. When you fail, you have to change the topic and start it from the beginning. That's the situation. @ColleenV The audience is the commission of supervisors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*This answer pertains to dissertation defenses in universities in the United States of America.* It would help if we knew which system, British or American that your university goes by.

If you are talking about presenting your "final results"  (that is, your dissertation) before your dissertation defense commmittee, this presentation is **part of** the defense of your dissertation, or your dissertation defense.

If you wish to refer to this part, you can say:

Dissertation presentation

Dissertation defense presentation

Dissertation oral defense presentation

Dissertation presentation at dissertation (or Ph.D.) defense

See (et al.):

1 [Hints for PhD Defenses](http://www.cs.columbia.edu/~hgs/etc/defense-hints.html) (Columibia University)

2 [Outline for presentations at final exams ("defenses") of doctoral dissertations](http://faculty.nps.edu/ncrowe/phd_defense_outline.htm)

> (a) Defenses usually consist of a presentation no longer than 45 minutes, followed by questioning from one to two hours.

3 [Preparing for your Doctoral Dissertation Defense](https://portfolio.du.edu/downloadItem/164641) (doc)

> Preparation for your Defense Meeting
>
> At your defense meeting, you’ll need to make a presentation lasting between 15-25 minutes.

4 [Ph.D. defense presentation](http://www.slideshare.net/mobile/phish108/prepare-your-phd-defense-presentation)

5 [Preparing for the oral defense of the dissertation](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CDQQFjAD&url=http%3A%2F%2Fasq.org%2Fedu%2F2010%2F01%2Fcareer-development%2Fpreparing-for-the-oral-defense-of-a-dissertation.pdf&ei=1FBbVYn1JMnxoASFo4GgBA&usg=AFQjCNFtH_l3AQyd4fnkReE5Bc0SGlXBvw&sig2=o1CRv7odG2761i1OLEMibg&bvm=bv.93756505,d.cGU) (pdf)